# C++ Printing DBL_MAX

Tags: c++, double, max, cout

I apologize if this has been asked before, but I read through many DBL_MAX threads and didn't see this exact issue.

In my `float.h` header the variable is defined as

```
#define DBL_MAX         1.7976931348623158e+308 /* max value */
```

However, whenever I try to print it in the console, I end up with 1.797693134862315**7**e+308 instead.

If this is supposed to be the maximum representable value, shouldn't it print correctly, without being rounded down? I have also set `out.precision` to the maximum value for doubles.

Can anyone explain why this is happening and advise whether or not there is a way to print out `DBL_MAX` unchanged?

Comment: Which platform?  (That is, which compiler, which standard library, and which OS?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the correct behaviour at both ends.

The maximum value representable in the so-called [binary64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) `double` representation your system seems to be using has an exponent of 1023, and a fraction of 1 - 2<sup>-52</sup>, to give (1 + 1-2<sup>-52</sup>)*2<sup>1023</sup> = (2<sup>1+52</sup>-2<sup>-52+52</sup>)*2<sup>1023-52</sup> = (2<sup>53</sup>-1)*2<sup>971</sup>, which according to `bc` evaluates to exactly

```
$ bc <<< '(2 ^ 53 - 1) * (2 ^ 971)'
17976931348623157081452742373170435679807056752584499659891747680315\
72607800285387605895586327668781715404589535143824642343213268894641\
82768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508\
45513394230458323690322294816580855933212334827479782620414472316873\
8177180919299881250404026184124858368
```

As you can see, this is `1.797693134862315708...e+308`, which is nearer to `1.7976931348623157e+308` than it is to `1.7976931348623158e+308`, which explains why you see `7` just before the `e` when printing this number.

However, the constant in the header has a slightly different purpose: its purpose is to always, no matter how the compiler is configured, give that exact floating-point number. Defining the constant as `1.7976931348623157e+308` would be incorrect, since that number is not exactly representable, the compiler is forced to round to either the previous or the next representable floating-point value, and it's possible that the compiler is configured to round down. Defining the constant as `1.7976931348623158e+308` does not have that problem, because it does not allow the compiler to round up, because there is no next (finite) value.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Great amount of detail, much appreciated :)